# Function minimization

Tags: calculus, derivatives, optimization, maxima-minima

I want to minimize the function $T(x)$.

$T(x)$  = $ \frac{\sqrt{(x - x_1)^2 + y_1^2}}{v_1} + \frac{\sqrt{(x - x_2)^2 + y_2^2}}{v_2} $

where $ x_1 , y_1, x_2, y_2, v_1, v_2$ are constants.

> I differentiated $T(x)$ with respect to $x$ i.e.
>
> $ \frac{dT}{dx}  = \frac{x- x_1}{v_1 \sqrt{(x - x_1)^2 + y_1^2}} + \frac{x- x_2}{v_2 \sqrt{(x - x_2)^2 + y_2^2}} = 0$
>
> But I was not able to find $x$ from the above equation.

The main goal is to find the minimum value of $T(x)$  $\forall x \in \Bbb R$

Comment: Put all the square roots on one side of the equation.  Then square.

Comment: @MatthewLeingang I tried that, but was not able to get _x_

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Snell%27s_law is easier to derive from Lagrange multipliers.

Comment: As a geometric alternative, apply a suitable dilation to the upper-half plane in order to regularize speeds, find a geodetic path (a straight line segment) there, apply the inverse dilation to the upper-half plane.

Comment: That gives that the wanted geodetic path crosses the $y=0$ line making two angles whose ratio of sines equals...

Comment: @JackD'Aurizio It is true that path of light takes the shortest time. But I am unable to get the expression for this value of time. Let source point be $(x_1, y_1)$ and speed in medium be $v_1$. Similarly let destination be $(x_2, y_2)$ and speed in that medium be $v_2$. What will be the value of time T?

Comment: Compute the point on the $x$-axis granting that Snell's law holds (there is only one point), then compute the lengths of the involved segments and find the minimal time.

Comment: Otherwise, once you have applied a dilation to the upper-half plane in order to travel with uniform speed $v$, just compute the distance between the source and the destination (after the transform) and divide it by $v$.

Comment: @JackD'Aurizio Applying Snell's Law gives the same equation as $\frac{dT}{dx}$ = 0 which was the initial question. I am not aware of the concept of dilation.

Comment: Snell's law is about a ratio of sines: how did you get $\frac{dT}{dx}=0$ from a ratio of sines?

Comment: @JackD'Aurizio Let the point on the interface of two mediums be $(x , 0)$. Then $ \sin \theta_1 = \frac{|x - x_1|}{\sqrt{(x-x_1)^2 +y_1^2}}  and \sin \theta_2 = \frac{|x - x_2|}{\sqrt{(x-x_2)^2 +y_2^2}}$ and by doing $ \frac{v_1}{\sin \theta_1} = \frac{v_2}{\sin \theta_2}$ we get the same equation ( In chat MathJax is not supported)

Comment: You have to find the only point on the $x$-axis for which the associated ratio of sines equals a certain ratio of speeds. Can you do that?

Comment: @JackD'Aurizio I am not sure I am getting you. I am saying that to find that point $(x , 0)$ it must satisfy the above mentioned equation which was what I was not able to solve originally. Since I only know the ratio of $\sin$ how can I precisely get the point without solving the equation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One possible solution from computer programming point of view would be to use a **ternary search** from the range $left = min(x_1,x_2)$ to $right = max(x_1, x_2)$ since the function $T(x)$ decreases and then increases from $(left,right)$ so we could determine the minima.
I think a mathematical solution would be rigorous but if someone wants to contribute then it will be very useful.